# Android CollapsingToolbar/ AppBarLayout scroll behind status bar behaviour top padding

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I'd like to use `CoordinatoryLayout`, `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to create a layout that resembles the below example from Google Calendar.

[image: Desired Google Calendar scroll behaviour]

The key things I'm trying to replicate:

- Scrolling the content behind the status bar
- Rounded corners at the top of the scroll container
- Enough room at the top of the screen for the header to not look squashed

**The Question**
Google Calendar appears to be growing the scroll container as the user scrolls. How would I go about doing this or something similar to achieve the look I'm after?

I've put together a quick example of what I'm trying to build:

**activity_scrolling.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context="uk.co.exampleapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/lay_header"
                layout="@layout/layout_header" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/scroll_header_background"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sectionTitleText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="Title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/filter_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".ScrollingActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**layout_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtitle"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**scroll_header_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <size
        android:width="64dp"
        android:height="64dp" />
</shape>
```

My attempt is included below. The header scrolls behind the toolbar as desired but I'd like some additional top padding above my views (about the height of the top inset/ status bar would be sufficient). Google Calendar appears to be solving this by having the container grow as the user scrolls.

[image: My attempt at scrolling][image: Screenshot]

Comment: In my case it's working fine, Can you add your theme?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman When you say 'it's working' what _exactly_ do you mean? The theme is the default with the addition of `translucentStatusBar=true` to enable the effect I've shown in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement an [AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener) that will adjust top padding on the *ConstraintLayout* that holds the *TextView* and the *Button*. (Call this view "viewToGrow".) You can also do other things in the listener like change the corner radius of the drawable as the appbar scrolls.

The following example adjusts top padding to give the header more room. This padding is increased as the appbar scrolls up and decreases as it scrolls down. The demo app also removes the corner radius of the drawable during the final 15% of the appbar scroll.

**ScrollingActivity**

```
class ScrollingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling)

        val viewToGrow: View = findViewById(R.id.viewToGrow)
        val baseTopPadding = viewToGrow.paddingTop

        // Determine how much top padding has to grow while the app bar scrolls.
        var maxDeltaPadding = 0
        val contentView = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(contentView) { _, insets ->
            maxDeltaPadding = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
            insets
        }

        // Get key metrics for corner radius shrikage.
        var backgroundRadii: FloatArray? = null
        var maxRadius: FloatArray? = null
        val backgroundDrawable = (viewToGrow.background as GradientDrawable?)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && backgroundDrawable != null) {
            backgroundRadii = backgroundDrawable.cornerRadii
            maxRadius = floatArrayOf(backgroundRadii!![0], backgroundRadii[1])
        }

        // Set up the app bar and the offset change listener.
        val appBar: AppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout)
        val appBarTotalScrollRange: Float by lazy {
            appBar.totalScrollRange.toFloat()
        }
        appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { _, verticalOffset ->
            // Add/remove padding gradually as the appbar scrolls.
            val percentOfScrollRange = (-verticalOffset / appBarTotalScrollRange)
            val deltaPadding = maxDeltaPadding * percentOfScrollRange
            val newTopPadding = baseTopPadding + deltaPadding.toInt()
            if (newTopPadding != viewToGrow.paddingTop) {
                viewToGrow.setPadding(
                    viewToGrow.paddingLeft,
                    newTopPadding,
                    viewToGrow.paddingRight,
                    viewToGrow.paddingBottom
                )
                // Change the drawable radius as the appbar scrolls.
                if (backgroundRadii != null && maxRadius != null) {
                    val radiusShrinkage = if (percentOfScrollRange > (1.0f - CORNER_SHRINK_RANGE)) {
                        (1.0f - percentOfScrollRange) / CORNER_SHRINK_RANGE
                    } else {
                        1.0f
                    }
                    backgroundRadii[0] = maxRadius[0] * radiusShrinkage
                    backgroundRadii[1] = maxRadius[1] * radiusShrinkage
                    backgroundRadii[2] = maxRadius[0] * radiusShrinkage
                    backgroundRadii[3] = maxRadius[1] * radiusShrinkage
                    backgroundDrawable!!.cornerRadii = backgroundRadii
                }
            }
        })
    }

    companion object {
        const val CORNER_SHRINK_RANGE = 0.15f
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to do this without the minimim api 24 call? @Cheticamp

Comment: @AndroidDev123 You are talking about `getCornerRadii()`? For APIs below 24, I would set a dimension in "dimens.xml" with the radius for the top corners. In the XML for the drawable, make a reference to that value in "<corners ...>". That will set up the drawable, You can get the value of the corners from the dimension value. The change in API 24 just make this process easier and a little more direct.